# gfortran compiler cannot find misspelled full directory

Tags: compilation, makefile, fortran, gfortran

I was able to make a much simpler example than the one in my original post. I'm trying to compile a fortran code using `gcc version 4.9.2 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev4, Built by MinGW-W64 project)` on windows.

Below is a batch script that I used to *successfully* compile the code:

```
  SET SRC_DIR=code
  gfortran -fopenmp -g -fimplicit-none -cpp ^
   %SRC_DIR%/globals/current_precision.f90^
   %SRC_DIR%/string/string.f90^
   ...
   %SRC_DIR%/user/MOONS.f90^
   parametricStudy.f90^
   -o main.exe
  del *.mod
```

The output looks like this:

```
  C:\Users\charl\Documents\GitHub\MOONS>gfortran -fopenmp -g -fimplicit-none -cpp  
  code/globals/current_precision.f90 
  code/string/string.f90 
   ...
  code/user/MOONS.f90 
  parametricStudy.f90 -o main.exe

  C:\Users\charl\Documents\GitHub\MOONS>del *.mod
```

Then I tried changing the source path from local to full by changing:

```
  SET SRC_DIR=code
```

to

```
  SET SRC_DIR=C:/Users/charl/Documents/GitHub/MOONS/code
```

But the output is now:

```
  C:\Users\charl\Documents\GitHub\MOONS>gfortran -fopenmp -g -fimplicit-none -cpp
  C:/Users/charl/Documents/GitHub/MOONS/code/globals/current_precision.f90 
   ...
  C:/Users/charl/Documents/GitHub/MOONS/code/solvers/induction/init_Bfield.f90 
  C:/Users/charl/Documents/GitHub
  gfortran: error: 
  C:/Users/charl/Documents/GitHubMOONS/code/solvers/induction/init_Sigma.f90: No such file or directory
```

I also tried *not* using variables and the same thing happened, so this seems to be related to the full path and not the use of variables. I have two questions

1) What is the reason for the error due to using the full path?

2) Why is there a misspelling in the full path? ("GitHubMOONS" should read "GitHub/MOONS")

Comment: Is that the only occurrence of `MOONS.o` in the list of files passed as arguments to that command? Or does it occur more than once with one being incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but the entire makefile is there, except the dotted lines under #*** INCLUDE PATHS *** and # *** SOURCE FILES ***. Everything below # *** DO NOT EDIT BELOW HERE *** is verbatim. As for the error, as you can see at the top, ..\\obj\MOONS.o is already created (and exists in the obj folder). I hope that helps

Comment: Is this the makefile in `$(TARGET_DIR)`? (If so what are those `run` and `myRun` targets for?) If not what does **that** makefile look like? And my question was about whether `MOONS.o` was listed on the command line being executed *twice* somehow?

Comment: The makefile is not in TARGET_DIR, it's in MAKE_DIR = C:$(PS)Users$(PS)$(USER)$(PS)Documents$(PS)GitHub$(PS)MOONS$(PS)makefiles$(PS)MOONS. Oh, sorry, I'll include that one too! And I'll check about your last question, right now the output has no line breaks so it's hard to read. I'll look and post soon.

Comment: The big makefile is calling the smaller makefile, which is located in TARGET_DIR. I haven't made any changes to the smaller one in a while, but at this point I'm open to any suggestions at all.

Comment: Oh, bah, I misread the `myRun` target. Sorry. Yeah, the big makefile is the important one.

Comment: Did you run make with debug flags to get the actual call taht is causing the error?

Comment: The error seems to happen whether I use debug or optimize flags. I was able to reproduce a similar error in a simpler example (using a batch script). I'll post these updates

Comment: The remark 2 (_"GitHubMOONS" should read "GitHub/MOONS"_) suggests there is a part with make that gets confused on `\` as a path separator and an escape for the next character. Is there a part (e.g. shell or cmd) that is called for command execution from make and that applies `\` interpretation as escape? Then maybe identify any part that is using `\` as a path separator...

Comment: I agree that that seems like the right approach to debug the problem, however, when I make small changes to the batch script (like including quotes, e.g.) the file that the compiler complains about **changes**. It seems that the best "solution" I'm realizing is to simply use local paths for the source files.. This doesn't result in any problems..

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is in the setting for SRC_DIR. This has to be in DOS format i.e.

```
*SET SRC_DIR=C:/Users/charl/Documents/GitHub/MOONS/code*
```

should be

```
*SET SRC_DIR=C:\Users\charl\Documents\GitHub\MOONS\code*
```

This is same reason for the misspelling in the full path.

Using the following command in the batch file, I could compile the code successfully:

gfortran -fopenmp -g -fimplicit-none -cpp "%SRC_DIR%\globals\current_precision.f90" %SRC_DIR%\string\string.f90 %SRC_DIR%\user\MOONS.f90 parametricStudy.f90 -o main.exe

Both, the full path  with filename in double quotes and without double quotes should work.

Comment: Your suggestion does not seem to work.. I tried both / and \ and full and relative paths. Both / and \ work for relative paths but do not work for full path. I tried with and without quotes as well. It seems to only work with relative paths.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the separator as follows:  C:\\Users\\charl\\Documents\\GitHub\\MOONS\\code. What system are you using?

Comment: Let me try that... No, that still results in the same misspelling error. I'm on Windows 10 Education, 64-bit.

Comment: Maybe the difference is due to the system. I could get it working on Windows 7 ( gfortran 4.5.3 for Cygwin 64 bit) using the following bat file.

Comment: This is certainly possible. I actually had it on a windows 7 machine, where the problem had existed before, but seemed dormant. When I push the same exact project to a windows 10 machine, I saw this error. I'm still not sure what the problem is though since I've seen it on both machines. One thing is clear though, both machines don't seem to have a problem with the relative path (so far).

Comment: You can try using the -v option for gfortran to diagnose the problem:      
 `setlocal
 echo off
 SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin\bin
 SET SRC_DIR=D:\Fortran\SO\code
 SET CPF90=%SRC_DIR%\globals\current_precision.f90
 SET STRF90=%SRC_DIR%\string\string.f90
 SET MNF90=%SRC_DIR%\user\MOONS.f90
 echo  %CPF90% %STRF90% %MNF90%
 
 gfortran -v -fopenmp -g -fimplicit-none -cpp  %CPF90% %STRF90% %MNF90% parametricStudy.f90 -o main.exe
 
 del *.mod
 endlocal`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to *use relative paths* for the source files. Doing so compiles fine without errors. If this somehow changes in the future, then I will update this post.

In short, just use

```
 SET SRC_DIR = code
```

Comment: It's been almost a month and I have not seen this error pop up again. I'm going to accept this answer.