# How does using modules that use other modules affect compilation? (gfortran)

Tags: compilation, fortran, gfortran

I asked a question about some strange behavior from a Fortran compiler here:

[gfortran compiler cannot find misspelled full directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313985/gfortran-compiler-cannot-find-misspelled-full-directory/36700100#36700100)

Basically, the compiler sporadically** complains that a file is missing, but the problem is that the printed name of the file (full path, actually) is misspelled, so no wonder it's "missing". I thought that I resolved the problem by using relative paths, but it turns out that the problem was just dormant. Here's an example of one such complaint:

```
C:\Users\charl\Documents\GitHub\MOONS>gfortran -fopenmp -g -fimplicit-none -cpp
C:/Users/charl/Documents/GitHub/MOONS/code/globals/current_precision.f90 
...
C:/Users/charl/Documents/GitHub/MOONS/code/solvers/induction/init_Bfield.f90 
C:/Users/charl/Documents/GitHub
gfortran: error: 
C:/Users/charl/Documents/GitHubMOONS/code/solvers/induction/init_Sigma.f90: No such file or directory
```

Notice that the forward slash ('/') is missing between GitHub and MOONS, and instead reads "GitHubMOONS". This path was correctly written in the makefile.

---

** I say sporadically because changing lines in the code sometimes results in the error disappearing. Similarly, removing some unused modules (that compile just fine) from my compilation list results in the error disappearing.

---

The compiler I'm using is:

```
 GNU Fortran (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2 Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

But I've seen the same problem with more recent compilers, e.g.:

```
 x86_64-7.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2
```

I think I am seeing a trend with when this error occurs, and it seems to occur more frequently when modules pass on public interfaces to other modules.

**Question**

So, my question is, given the following two modules:

```
   module add_int_mod
   implicit none
   private
   public :: add
   interface add; module procedure add_int; end interface
   contains
   subroutine add_int(a,b)
     implicit none
     integer,intent(inout) :: a
     integer,intent(in) :: b
     a = a + b
   end subroutine
   end module

   module add_all_mod
   use add_int_mod
   implicit none
   private
   public :: add
   end module
```

What is the difference between these two programs, if any?

Program 1

```
   program main
   use add_all_mod                         ! only difference
   implicit none
   integer :: a,b
   a = 0
   b = 1
   call add(a,b)
   write(*,*) 'a = ',a
   write(*,*) 'b = ',b
   end program
```

Program 2

```
   program main
   use add_int_mod                         ! only difference
   implicit none
   integer :: a,b
   a = 0
   b = 1
   call add(a,b)
   write(*,*) 'a = ',a
   write(*,*) 'b = ',b
   end program
```

I appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: They're included in the old question. I'll attach a snippet of it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Not at all. What has the code and the modules have to do with the path problem?

Comment: I would rather investigate the Makefile. Namely, does this problem happen when you call gfortran directly from the command line? How exactly does the complete line by which gfortran is called by `make` look like? How does the Makefile rule that produced the line look like?

Comment: Or if gfortran is called directly without make, than does it happen always? Does the problem always appear at the same place in the directory name? There can be some strange compiler bug somewhere, but I would be surprised if such a thing was done by the Fortran frontend, that will likely be some common GCC code.